# Mapbox GL - Fullscreen control not working, it is not a constructor

Tags: fullscreen, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I would like to add the fullscreen control to my map, but for some reason, it doesnt work. I am following tutorial from this link - https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/fullscreen/

So to add the FullscreenControl, I use the following code

```
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.FullscreenControl());
```

However, it doesnt work, when I compile the project, I see this error in the console - "*Uncaught TypeError: mapboxgl.FullscreenControl is not a constructor*"

Interestingly, when I use the same code to add the Navigation control, all works as expected.

```
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl())
```

Does anyone have an idea where is the problem and why I am able to use that code to add NavigationControl, but not the FullscreenControl?

Thanks a lot

Comment: without seeing your code its hard to debug - can you post a sample? My inital thoughts are you are not including the right version of MapboxGL. Also check the function FullScreenControl() it should have content in the function if you see FullScreenControl() {} only this would be the problem! i.e wrong version of MapBoxGL

Comment: Hi, thank you, that was indeed the root of the problem - I was referencing the version version 0.32.1 . Once I replaced it by version 0.41.0, it started to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was hinted in comments, problem was with the version. I was referencing the older version 0.32.1 . Once I replaced it by version 0.41.0, it started to work